# Failed to obtain p value using Svyolr () function in R

Tags: regression, logistic, survey, ordinal-data

I wish to carry out an ordinal logistic regression taking into account the weightings.
With the help of the function `svyolr` of the `survey` package, I manage to obtain the estimates and confidence intervals. However, I am not able to estimate the p-values. Would you have a solution, please?

```r
library(survey)

reglog<-svyolr(as.factor(TBHYP)~ COUPLE + SITUATIONPROPAR + TELETRAVAILPAR + DIFFINANCE + ... + ZONE RESID,method="logistic,design=dw,na.action=na.omit)

summary(reglog)
confint(reglog)
```